# beats tempo relationship

Tags: theory, tempo

If beats and tempo are not related then can you have a tempo (BPM) without first knowing the beat (having a beat.) ie 0 beats = no tempo or tempo zero and infinity. 1 beat = tempo of infinity and 2 beats equal an exact bpm (tempo)

There are several software beat counting programs - they can only work if they can sample at high frequency and determine the smallest beat time frequency as a factor of the highest beat time frequency.

Comment: Is your question, "*can you have a tempo (BPM) without first knowing the beat (having a beat.)*"? If that is your question, it's not totally clear to me. Can you explain what you mean by "knowing the beat" or "having a beat"? A lot of times, a tempo is specified. By that I mean, someone might say, "play this music at 90 beats per minute". That's all you need to "have a tempo", in general. When some says "play at 90 beats per minute", you also have to know what counts as a beat. Usually that's a quarter note (crotchet) or eighth note (quaver). Is that what you're asking?

Comment: yes actually there is a sample rate of 43000Hz or 43000 times per second (or something like that) , which is what most sound files on your computer will use.  However, considering something like vinyl where there is no digitization of information... you can have music that comes from analog ("infinite sample rate") sources, however, there must essentially be a perception of a beat for there to be music.

Comment: I have edited the question to try and remove some unneeded text, but I have to admit it still doesn't make any sense to me. I think your key assumption is incorrect - beats and tempo are related!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not clear what the question is, or even if there is a question.

Answer (score 1):

Pragmatically: the Beat is mostly for writing purposes.  "Pulse" is often used synonymously with beat and if I start clapping a "pulse," or "beat," you wouldn't know if it's a quarter-note or an eighth-note etc.  It is a pulse, an undefined beat.  It has a tempo but not necessarily the same as the song tempo.  We get the song tempo once we decide what the beat is.

EXAMPLE: I clap a "pulse" at 80 BPM.  I then decide the song has a "double-time feel" so the pulse is half notes; quarter notes are 160 BPM, the tempo is 160 BPM.

In other words the pulse is the feel of the song.  The way you choose to write it gives the value of the beat and the tempo.  Pulse has a BPM but it might differ from the beat because of the way you want to write the music notes.

Comment: thanks, 'feel likes' is probably what I'm trying to comprehend the mechanics of

Comment: Thanks everyone, Beat is the key to the rythme. BPM and TEmpo more measures. If you say ' play at 80 BPM' how do you know what time to leave between the first and second notes? You don't, because its not some calculable time until after the beat or groove has been created.